# Не получается правильно считать и вывести строку при перехвате 4Bh int21h из регистра DX

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Собственно, проблема лежит в заголовке. ***Есть резидент, обрабатывающий 4Bh, который должен в заносить в newprogname имя программы.*** Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так? Прикладываю код обработки прерывания 21h и печати строки. Весь код программы есть в предыдущем вопросе.

```
 new_21h proc far
        pushf  ; сохраняем флаги
        cmp   AH, 4Bh ;4Bh - функция запуска новой программы
        je    newprog ; Да? прыгаем на новый обработчик
        popf   ; иначе восстанавливаем флаги (которые изменял cmp)
        jmp   dword ptr CS:[old_21h]  ; прыгаем в системный обработчик без возврата
    newprog:
        push  DS
        push AX
        Push CX
        push di
        push  CS    ;   настройка DS
        pop   DS

        lea di ,newprogname ; Куда записывать строку
        ml:
        cmp byte ptr [DX],0 ; Сравниваем символ с 0(строка заканчивается символом нуля)
        je ex       
        mov Al ,byte ptr [DX];В AL кладем очередной символ
        mov [di] ,AL
        inc di
        inc DX;
        jmp ml
        ex:

        pop di
        pop CX
        pop AX
        pop   DS
        popf        ; не забываем флаги, которые сохраняли в самом начале
        jmp   dword ptr CS:[old_21h]
        iret
    new_21h endp



    ; ------------------------ Позиционируем курсор -----------------------------
        mov     AH,02h          ; Функция позиционирования
        mov     BH,CS:page_num  ; Видеостраница
        mov     DH,CS:coordnewprog_y   ; Строка
        mov     DL,CS:coordnewprog_x   ; Столбец
        int 10h
    ;------------------------- Распечатаем имя этой программы--------------------
        mov     CX,8
        mov     BX, offset  CS:newprogname 
        mov     AH,0Eh                 ;По одному символу
    next_sym2:
        mov     AL,CS:[BX]             ; Символ в AL
        inc     BX                     ; Сдвиг по строке
        int     10h                    
        loop    next_sym2              ; Цикл по строке
        ; восстановление регистров из стека в порядке LIFO
        pop DI
        pop     DS  
        pop     DX
        pop     CX
        pop     BX
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newprog:

push ax bx cx dx ds si DI ES; сохраняем все используемые регистры в стеке

    push dx;  заносим в регистр SI сегмент, в котором

    pop si; - содержится имя запускаемой программы

    mov bx,0; обнуляем регистр BX (для длины)

m1:
    mov al,ds: [si+bx] ; 
    mov cs: newprogname [bx],al; ¦ копируем имя программы в переменную
    inc bx; 
    cmp al,0; конец строки завершается нуликом
    jnz m1
    mov cs: len,bx; сохраняем длину строки  
    pop ES DI SI DS DX CX BX AX ;восстанавливаем регистры
    popf        ; не забываем флаги, которые сохраняли в самом начале
    jmp   dword ptr CS:[old_21h]
    iret
new_21h endp
```